# Custom wp.editor.initialize settings ignored

Tags: javascript, visual-editor, wp-editor

I built a meta box where a click on a button shows a textarea with rich text editing enabled. After creating the textarea and appending it to the DOM, I run this to initialize the editor:

```
console.log(wp.editor.getDefaultSettings());
var settings = {
    tinymce: {toolbar1:"bold,italic,bullist,link"}
};
wp.editor.initialize( contentID, settings);
```

As a result the textarea appears and tinymce get intialized on it. The issue is that my custom settings have no effect. In the above example I still get the numlist button, whereas it isn't specified in the settings:

[image: editor example]

According to [the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/wp.editor#wp.editor.initialize) my own settings should be merged with default settings which seems to not happen as `wp.editor.getDefaultSettings()` returns:

```
{
   "tinymce":{
      "theme":"modern",
      "skin":"lightgray",
      "language":"fr",
      "formats":{
         "alignleft":[
            {
               "selector":"p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li",
               "styles":{
                  "textAlign":"left"
               }
            },
            {
               "selector":"img,table,dl.wp-caption",
               "classes":"alignleft"
            }
         ],
         "aligncenter":[
            {
               "selector":"p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li",
               "styles":{
                  "textAlign":"center"
               }
            },
            {
               "selector":"img,table,dl.wp-caption",
               "classes":"aligncenter"
            }
         ],
         "alignright":[
            {
               "selector":"p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li",
               "styles":{
                  "textAlign":"right"
               }
            },
            {
               "selector":"img,table,dl.wp-caption",
               "classes":"alignright"
            }
         ],
         "strikethrough":{
            "inline":"del"
         }
      },
      "relative_urls":false,
      "remove_script_host":false,
      "convert_urls":false,
      "browser_spellcheck":true,
      "fix_list_elements":true,
      "entities":"38,amp,60,lt,62,gt",
      "entity_encoding":"raw",
      "keep_styles":false,
      "cache_suffix":"wp-mce-4800-20180716-tadv-4.7.13",
      "resize":"vertical",
      "menubar":false,
      "branding":false,
      "preview_styles":"font-family font-size font-weight font-style text-decoration text-transform",
      "end_container_on_empty_block":true,
      "wpeditimage_html5_captions":true,
      "wp_lang_attr":"fr-FR",
      "wp_keep_scroll_position":false,
      "wp_shortcut_labels":{
         "Heading 1":"access1",
         "Heading 2":"access2",
         "Heading 3":"access3",
         "Heading 4":"access4",
         "Heading 5":"access5",
         "Heading 6":"access6",
         "Paragraph":"access7",
         "Blockquote":"accessQ",
         "Underline":"metaU",
         "Strikethrough":"accessD",
         "Bold":"metaB",
         "Italic":"metaI",
         "Code":"accessX",
         "Align center":"accessC",
         "Align right":"accessR",
         "Align left":"accessL",
         "Justify":"accessJ",
         "Cut":"metaX",
         "Copy":"metaC",
         "Paste":"metaV",
         "Select all":"metaA",
         "Undo":"metaZ",
         "Redo":"metaY",
         "Bullet list":"accessU",
         "Numbered list":"accessO",
         "Insert/edit image":"accessM",
         "Remove link":"accessS",
         "Toolbar Toggle":"accessZ",
         "Insert Read More tag":"accessT",
         "Insert Page Break tag":"accessP",
         "Distraction-free writing mode":"accessW",
         "Keyboard Shortcuts":"accessH"
      },
      "content_css":"https://[redacted]/dev/www/core/wp-includes/css/dashicons.css?ver=4.9.8,https://[redacted]/dev/www/core/wp-includes/js/tinymce/skins/wordpress/wp-content.css?ver=4.9.8",
      "toolbar1":"bold,italic,bullist,numlist,link",
      "wpautop":false,
      "indent":true,
      "elementpath":false,
      "plugins":"charmap,colorpicker,hr,lists,paste,tabfocus,textcolor,fullscreen,wordpress,wpautoresize,wpeditimage,wpemoji,wpgallery,wplink,wptextpattern"
   },
   "quicktags":{
      "buttons":"strong,em,link,ul,ol,li,code"
   }
}
```

Any idea of what I may be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found: the settings have to have `quicktags` defined:

```
var settings = {
    tinymce: {toolbar1:"bold,italic,bullist,link"},
    quicktags: {
        "buttons": "strong,em,link,ul,li,code"
    }
};
wp.editor.initialize( contentID, settings);
```